# Unable to mount partition

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, partition, diskutil

I've combined two partition formatted as NTFS for dual boot system with bootcamp. I did this while running windows using a special program to adjust partitions.
but after a necessary restart according the program some texts rolled by.
after that i lost access to the bootmanager and was unable to choice to boot to windows or Macintosh.

now I installed a fresh copy of mac os on the old partition where Windows was installed before.
I figured out that the partition where my Mac installation was on still exists, but its name has changed to "Windows Recovery" somehow.

disk0s2 is for as far as I know still the partition where my files are on.

what I like to accomplish now is get access somehow to this partition and copy my files before completely format the whole disk and install a fresh installation of Mac OS.

please help!

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Below is the output from the following commands.

```
diskutil unmount disk0s2
sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=3 | hexdump -Cv
```

[image: Requested info]

[image: Requested info2]

Below is the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`.

```
   Partition Offset: 314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size: 351.0 GB (351027175424 Bytes) (exactly 685599952 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size: 4096 Bytes
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Files and folders inside EFI disk]

Comment: Add to your question the output from the command `diskutil unmount disk0s2` followed by `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=3 | hexdump -Cv`. Basically, `disk0s2` has the wrong GUID partition type in the GPT. However, before fixing this problem, I want to see if the header is correct for a APFS container.

Comment: I'm not familiar how to answer to you're question, but I posted two screenshots in my original question.

Comment: I can post the commands needed to fix your problem. It would be helpful if you could first post the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset`.

Comment: jeffrey2@jeffrey2s-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
   Partition Offset:          314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 351.0 GB (351027175424 Bytes) (exactly 685599952 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes
jeffrey2@jeffrey2s-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the command given below.

```
diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
```

You should see output similar to what is shown below.

```
   Partition Offset: 314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size: 351.0 GB (351027175424 Bytes) (exactly 685599952 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size: 4096 Bytes
```

You need to determine the offset and size in units of device blocks. In your case, the offset is `76806 Blocks` and the size is `200000118784 Bytes/4096 Bytes per Block=85699994 Blocks`.

Next, you need to boot to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). Basically, restart the Mac and hold down the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination until macOS Recovery starts to boot.

From the menu bar, open a Terminal application window. Enter the following commands.

```
gpt -f remove -i 2 disk0
gpt -f add -i 2 -b 76806 -s 85699994 -t apfs disk0
```

### Removing the APFS Container with the `Untitled` and `Untitled - Data` Volumes

The following commands can be use to remove this container. Here I assume you have booted from the macOS stored in the other container.

```
sudo diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s3
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

An alternative and perhaps safer way to remove this container would be to first boot to macOS Recovery over the Internet, a macOS installation flash drive or an external drive with macOS installed. Next, enter the following commands.

```
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0.
```

Next, reboot back to macOS.

When finished, the drive will contain 150 GB of free space. This free space can be added to the remaining APFS container by entering the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: @Jeffrey: You have already done some of these steps.

Comment: OMG! at first when terminal answered "removed" after the first command I was a little shocked, but after the second command and restarted it started to load the correct version of Mac OS X 
YOUR'E AMAZING!!

Comment: Is it okay to delete the two partitions where I installed the second Mac OS on?  "Untitled and Untitled - Data"  please check the picture above.

Comment: The safest answer would be to boot to macOS Recovery over the Internet, a macOS installation flash drive or an external drive with macOS installed. Next, enter the command `diskutil unmountdisk disk0` followed by `gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0`.

Comment: This will delete the two unneeded partitions Untitled and Untitled - Data, but keeps the partitions we just recovered?

Comment: It is not just the volumes `Untitled` and `Untitled - Data`. These and other hidden volumes exist in the APFS container stored in partition `disk0s3`. See your original `diskutil list disk0` output posted in your question. If you remove this partition, then all the volumes as well as the container will be removed. This will create 150 GB of free space. The commands I posted are not only way, but rather the safest way. The partition you just recovered is `disk0s2`. This is a different container. Look at the current output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: I'm sorry to hassestate on your answer, but haven't we just recovered disk 0 what does s2 actually means?

Comment: i'll post a new screenshot to be sure

Comment: I think I understand it now, I have two containers named disk0s2 with 351.0 GB with includes partitions Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - Data. and disk0s3 with 148.9 GB which concludes partitions Untitled and Untitled - Data which I want to remove. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. you have two containers. One container is in a partition identified as `disk0s2`. (This means disk 0 slice 2.)  This container holds the volumes labeled `Macintosh HD` and `Macintosh HD - Data` plus 3 other hidden volumes. The other container is in a partition identified as `disk0s3`. This container holds the volumes labeled `Untitled` and `Untitled - Data` plus 3 other hidden volumes. If you remove this partition then you will remove the container and all the volumes the container holds. So you are right, you want to remove `disk0s3`.

Comment: so the command you gave me is still correct? diskutil unmountdisk disk0 followed by gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0

Comment: Yes. Also, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I have one more question related to all this. how do I get rid of the partition EFI next to Macintosh HD when holding down option key? I prefer to see recovery there.

Comment: Do you mean an icon with the label `EFI Boot`?

Comment: yes, when restarting and when i'm holding down option key it shows two hard drive icons. one EFI and one Macintosh HD

Comment: please check screenshot of Files and folders inside EFI disk. I think it has something to do with the folder Boot with the following file inside bootx64.efi

Comment: I also noticed that my EFI partition is a little bigger then most people's EFI partition. mine is 314.6 MB what I see most people have 209.7 MB

Comment: I followed these steps, you're steps and the disk icon at startup is gone now, but I'm still wondering why mine EFI partition is bigger then most out there.

Comment: The ghost is being caused by the file efi/boot/bootx64.efi stored in the EFI partition.

Open a Terminal window and enter the following command.
diskutil mount /dev/disk0s1
From a Finder window, open the EFI disk. Next open the EFI folder. Remove the Boot and Microsoft folders.
When finished, enter the command below.
diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s1

Comment: Originally, the EFI partition was 209.7 MB. This is sufficiently large when the device block size is 512 bytes. However, you have a newer drive, where the device block size is 4096 bytes. The EFI partition is FAT32 formatted. In order to correctly FAT32 format a partition, the partition must be a minimum size. This size is dependent on the device block size. **A size of 209.7 MB is large enough when the device block size is 512 MB, but to small when the device block size is 4096 bytes.** To solve this problem, the size was increased to 314.6 MB.

Comment: You can get more information about the size requirements for the EFI partition by reading the Microsoft document [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions) .